# OpenAPI spec in yaml or json format and parse in c#

Tags: c#, json, linq, openapi

How do I take a large OpenAPI spec in yaml or json format and flatten it to produce summary, tag, path, httpMethod in C#?

Assume use JObject SelectTokens but I can't figure out the syntax.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText ("spec.json");
JObject array = JObject.Parse(json);
array.SelectTokens("paths").Dump();
```

Here's a sample json spec

```
{
    "paths": {
        "/entities/{id}": {
            "get": {

                "summary": "Get Entity",

                "tags": [
                    "Things"
                ]
            },
            "put": {

                "summary": "Update Entity",

                "tags": [
                    "Things"
                ]
            }
        },
        "/otherEntities/{id}": {
            "get": {

                "summary": "Get Other",

                "tags": [
                    "Others"
                ]
            },
            "put": {

                "summary": "Update Other",

                "tags": [
                    "Others"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would want:

```
"Get Entity", "Things", "/entities/{id}", "get"
"Update Entity", "Things", "/entities/{id}", "put"
"Get Other", "Others", "/otherEntities/{id}", "get"
"Update Other", "Others", "/otherEntities/{id}", "put"
```

Comment: Consider using an OpenAPI parser such as [OpenAPI.NET](https://github.com/Microsoft/OpenAPI.NET). OpenAPI parsers can read both YAML and JSON and handle `$ref` references among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Iterate the `paths`.

   1.1. Convert `JObject` to `Dictionary` for `paths` JObject.
2. Iterate as `KeyValuePair` from *1.1*.

   2.1. Get the key as `path`.

   2.1. Convert the value of the dictionary as `methodKvp`.
3. Iterate as `KeyValuePair` from *2.2*.

   3.1. Get the key as `method`.

   3.2. Get the `summary` from token "summary".

   3.3. Get the tag with first value of the array from token "tags".

   3.4. Add extracted values to list.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<List<string>> result = new ();

foreach (JObject pathObj in array.SelectTokens("paths").AsJEnumerable())
{           
    Dictionary<string, JObject> pathDict = pathObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>(); 

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JObject> pathKvp in pathDict)
    {
        var path = pathKvp.Key;
        var methodDict = pathKvp.Value.ToObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JObject> methodKvp in methodDict)
        {
            string method = methodKvp.Key;
            string summary = (string)methodKvp.Value.SelectToken("summary");
            string tag = (string)methodKvp.Value.SelectToken("tags").AsEnumerable().First();

            result.Add(new List<string> { summary, tag, path, method });
        }
    }       
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YEes69)